# Hide footer in Adobe Form based on line items field

Tags: adobe, livecycle-designer, sap-basis, adobe-form

This is an Adobe Form development. I have a requirement where I should display/hide a field in footer in a page and this footer should be displayed/hidden based on a flag which is a field in the line items internal table.

I have a table with products of a quotation and this table has a flag for used items. There can be more than 100 products per quotation. I have displayed this table using subforms and floating fields.

[image: Products subform]

The refurbished indicator in the above image is already handled using FormCalc and is working fine.

[image: Product subform hierarchy]
[image: Structure of product item table]

The footer cannot be clubbed with the product item subform. 
If there is a used product is displayed in a particular page, then the footer should display a disclaimer statement only in that page.

[image: Footnote disclaimer]

Kindly someone help me out how to achieve this.

Comment: Show form interface and form layout

Comment: Updated the question with screenshots of layout

Answer (score 1):

For conditional showing of some field use following FormCalc code:

```
if ( gt_product_i.data.refurb.rawValue == "X" ) then
  $.presence = "visible"
else
  $.presence = "hidden"
endif
```

Insert the code into script event "Initialize", which can be accessed by Ctrl-Shift-F5 (Script Editor) and selecting event in field "Show"

[image]

Screen is given just for reference and does not represent current question.